Returning the aggregate of the last 3 rows of an occurrence in google sheets
I have a growing table from A:Bl.  It grows by rows, not columns.  I am try to write a xlookup formula that will search column D and find the last three occurrences of English

and return those 3 rows from column E:Bl
instead of returning the three separate rows of values.  I would like one row returned that would have the the sum the 3 rows

ex.  English - 5 - 5 - 5...
instead of:
English - 2 - 2 - 2...
English - 2 - 2 - 2...
English - 1 - 1 - 1...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UAcQHEUvqHrIrilEgUlEQrpaOpRnbR7iOsDMIp_LRgA/edit?usp=sharing
I have tried this:=XLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(3), ROW(D2:D), INDEX(FILTER(E2:BL, D2:D="English"), ), , -1)
It doesnt work... I am looking for a formula and not app script. If Query / Sum / index  Is better, those solutions would be acceptable

You may try this formula for one language:
=ArrayFormula(LET(lang,A2:A13,
                  toSum,B2:E13,
                  langCond,"English",
                  rowNum,ROW(lang),
                  reverseInstance,COUNTIFS(lang,lang,rowNum,">="&rowNum),
                  createArr,SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(lang),1,0),
                  total,MMULT(createArr,(lang=langCond)*(reverseInstance<=3)*toSum),
                  total))


If you need to search multiple languages, you can also try this array version:
=ArrayFormula(LET(lang,A2:A14,
                  toSum,B2:E14,
                  langCond,F5:F7,
                  rowNum,ROW(lang),
                  reverseInstance,COUNTIFS(lang,lang,rowNum,">="&rowNum),
                  total,MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(lang)=langCond),(reverseInstance<=3)*toSum),
                  total))



Try
=SUM(CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(E2:BL,D2:D="English"),-1,-2,-3))


QUERY() may be better choice.


You may try:
=let(Λ,ifna(filter(E:H,D:D="English ")),
 bycol(chooserows(Λ,sequence(min(3,rows(Λ)),1,-1,-1)),lambda(Σ,sum(Σ))))



FYI there's a trailing space for the term English 

